# how to set Postion of static block on homepage?

Tags: magento2, static-block

I have created a static block programmatically on homepage. but it shows after the heading title. i want to set position for it.
[image]

I want this ***New Block*** block between **Registered Customer** and **New Customer** blocks. anyone help me how can i do this programmatically?

code for this: 
in layout :

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Newblock" name="customer.newblock" template="form/newblock.phtml"/>
```

In block:

```
 <?php
 namespace Magento\Customer\Block\Form;
class Newblock
   extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
   public function getTitle()
  {
      return "New Block";
  }
}
```

In templates :

```
   <h1><?php echo $block->getTitle(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: show code for your block

Comment: see my code @Rakesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set your xml like this,

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Newblock" name="customer.newblock" template="form/newblock.phtml" after="customer_form_login"/>
```

Remove cache and check your block position.